# Is there any way to train a sklearn model by disk data like HDF5 or such ?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In my problem, I have very large dataset which is out of my memory. I would like to train my model by using disk data like HDF5 or such. Does sklearn support this or is there any other alternative ?

Comment: This question assumes that in principle all models can be trained without having all the data in memory. I doubt that this is the case.

Comment: This is perfectly possible, for instance Caffe uses db like structure to fetch data from disk as the training goes.

Comment: Ogrisel provided an answer but have you found any additional ways? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: you could use generators in the first steps of your processing pipeline and load the full data only when the size is small enough.

Answer (score 5):

What you ask for is called out-of-core or streaming learning. It is only possible with a subset of the scikit-learn models that implement the `partial_fit` method for incremental fitting.

There is an [example in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html#example-applications-plot-out-of-core-classification-py). There is no specific utility to fit models on data in HDF5 in particular but can can adapt this example to fetch the data from any external datasource (e.g. HDF5 data on the local disk or a database over the network, for instance using the pandas SQL adapter).